# Does temp table in sql-server support where clause?

Tags: sql-server

I am learning transact sql on https://data.stackexchange.com/

I wrote this snippet to count how many users created just one post.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as post_count, OwnerUserId
INTO #tb_postcount
FROM posts
group by OwnerUserId
order by post_count desc, OwnerUserId desc;

SELECT count(*)
from #tb_postcount 
where post_count =1
group by OwnerUserId
order by post_count desc, OwnerUserId desc
```

And I got

> Column "#tb_postcount.post_count" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I guess this is because temp table in sql-server does not support where clause, I don't even know if sql-server does support or does not.

How to have my query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message says that you can'y use this column in a GROUP BY, your WHERE condition is perfectly fine.
Try following query to get how many users created just one post:

```
SELECT count(*)
from #tb_postcount 
where post_count =1
```